# ATG 10 on WebLogic Lock Manager Configuration

Tags: weblogic-10.x, atg, oracle-commerce

I am trying to configure the Lock Manager instances for Oracle ATG 10.2 running on WebLogic 10.3.6 and was wondering if these instances absolutely need database connectivity? We plan to only run the ServerLockManager components on these servers and nothing else.

Thoughts?

Comment: what's your configuration?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?  If you are asking for the ATG configuration then this does not exist yet for the Lock Manager instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you may be able to create your own ATG module which only has your only server lock manager components defined and you could only startup that single module on your 'lock manager' weblogic instances. This would require quite a bit of customization to configuration and I have never seen it done across the handful of customers I have worked on, so it is not common and you will likely have some difficulties implementing and getting proper support from Oracle if you do have issues with repositories / lock managers in the future.

In any case, there is a chance that depending upon your repository and lock server configurations, the lock manager components you start up may have required dependencies on other components that ultimately have dependencies on DB based repositories. So, in the end you may likely require DB connectivity regardless.

Comment: Thanks - in the end had to deploy a full module with DB connectivity.  It seems crazy though as the ServerLockManager lock tables are managed in memory and do not seem to require database connectivity.  I was trying to create a light weight lock managers.